# SSL Certificate configuration for WSO2 API 3.2

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I'm currently trying to configure our WSO2 API Manager 3.2 to use our SSL certificate.
I followed the documentation "Creating a New Keystore" and "Configuring Keystores in API Manager".

I have updated the deployment.toml file:

```
[server]<br>
hostname = "myserver001.internal.net"
....

[keystore.tls]
file_name =  "myKeystore.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "secretpassword"
alias =  "myserver001.internal.net"
key_password =  "secretpassword"

[keystore.primary]
file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "wso2carbon"
alias =  "wso2carbon"
key_password =  "wso2carbon"
```

The servername is set to myserver001.
The domain name myserver001.internal.net is set in the host file.

After restarting the WSO2 APIM server an exception message is thrown:

SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match:

```
  <localhost> != <myserver001.internal.net> OR <myserver001.internal.net>
```

Does anyone knows what I have to change additionally, to come around this error or where I can find additional documentation?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is happening due to the hostname verification. You can change the localhost values to myserver001.internal.net. And then put an /etc/host entry pointing myserver001.internal.net to localhost. Can u share the complete error msg?

Comment: [2020-10-22 08:41:44,564]  WARN - SubscriptionDataLoaderImpl Failed retrieving /subscriptions from remote endpoint: hostname in certificate didn't match: <localhost> != <myserver001.internal.net> OR <myserver001.internal.net>. Retrying after 15 seconds.
The localhost value is set to myserver001 and the entry in the host file is set.
[server]
hostname = "myserver001.internal.net"

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am using 3.6 version of WSO2 (moving from 2.6) and getting the same error.

Comment: No, no solution right now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks this is due to the missing `service_url` of TM/Event hub config. So can you add/update the following config?

```
[apim.throttling]
...
service_url = "https://myserver001.internal.net:9443/services/"
```

Comment: Thank you for this tip but this error messages are there for
/apis, /subscriptions, /api-policies, /application-key-mappings, /application-policies, /subscription-policies   
and other contexte. Always the same error message:
hostname in certificate didn't match: <localhost> != <myserver001.internal.net> <br>
Any idea?

Comment: Does your cert have correct CN? ex: myserver001.internal.net

Comment: Yes, the cert is used in our preprod environment. I am just trying to migrate to the newest WSO2 APIM version. Our actual version 2.6 and it is working fine but even there it was a nightmare to configure the SSL certificate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the exact same situation :

- Migration from v2.6.0 to v3.2.0
- Valid certificate
- SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match

I tried a lot of things, but after a lot of researches, I'd say that there is two possibilities :

- It's a bug
- It's a documentation problem, and we have to edit more things to make our certificate work

I believe that you changed the Dhttpclient.hostnameVerifier to another value than "AllowAll". See [the doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/security/enabling-hostname-verification/) about hostname verification.

It's just a workaround and it's probably not that secure, but you'll have to put back the default value for Dhttpclient.hostnameVerifier to avoid this error :

```
service wso2am-3.2.0 stop
nano /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.2.0/bin/wso2server.sh
```

> -Dhttpclient.hostnameVerifier=AllowAll \

```
service wso2am-3.2.0 start
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this setting is definitively not allowed in our environment.
I have to investigate more.....

Comment: I understand. Another possible solution would be to upgrade from v3.2.0 to v3.2.0.2... But you'll need to pay for that I guess.