# WSO2 API Manager 4.2.0 - custom TLS keystore - Let's Encrypt - Error Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names

Tags: wso2-api-manager

**Problem**

We are trying to configure WSO2 API Manager 4.2.0 to use a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate in the TLS keystore.

We encounter an error upon API-M startup
`Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [server-apim.mydomain.com].`

We followed the documentation "Creating New Keystores" and "Configuring Keystores in WSO2 API Manager".

Steps:

1. Created a new Let's Encrypt key for the API-M server (server-apim.mydomain.com).
2. Created a new keystore containing Let's Encrypt key/cert
3. Updated the client-truststore.jks to include the public certificate for the Let's Encrypt key.
4. Updated the deployment.toml file so that the TLS keystore points at the new keystore. Retained the default wso2carbon keystore for the primary and internal keystores.

```
[keystore.tls]
file_name =  "newkeystore.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "newpassword"
alias =  "domain"
key_password =  "newpassword"

[keystore.primary]
file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "wso2carbon"
alias =  "wso2carbon"
key_password =  "wso2carbon"

[keystore.internal]
file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "wso2carbon"
alias =  "wso2carbon"
key_password =  "wso2carbon"
```

After restarting the WSO2 API M service, we encounter errors in the wso2carbon.log that prevent a clean start. For example:

```
TID: [] [] [2023-14-07 14:39:04,054] WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.correlation.CorrelationConfigManager} - Failed retrieving correlation configs. Retrying after 2 seconds...
TID: [] [] [2023-14-07 14:39:04,055] WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.loader.KeyManagerConfigurationDataRetriever} - Failed retrieving Key Manager Configurations from remote endpoint. Retrying after 2 seconds...
TID: [] [] [2023-14-07 14:39:04,132] WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.model.impl.SubscriptionDataLoaderImpl} - Failed retrieving /apis?gatewayLabel=Default from remote endpoint: Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [server-apim.mydomain.com]. Retrying after 15 seconds.
```

**Research**: I have found two related questions, though they did not seem to provide the solution.

[wso2-am-ssl-cert-issued-for-host-name-in-conflict-with-localhost-calls-in-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73925061/wso2-am-ssl-cert-issued-for-host-name-in-conflict-with-localhost-calls-in-prod)

[ssl-certificate-configuration-for-wso2-api-3-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64466107/ssl-certificate-configuration-for-wso2-api-3-2)

- We cannot add 'Localhost' as a SAN in the certificate as this is not permitted by Let's Encrypt. Is this a showstopper?
- We have hostname verification enabled.
- We have a single API-M all in one instance on one server behind a reverse proxy that is on another server.

Any suggestions welcome. Has anyone else used an SSL certificate (without localhost as a SAN), and had to make other API-M configuration changes to allow these internal localhost calls?

Comment: We can update the internal service call URLs with your Server domain name to overcome the mentioned error message. Can you try adding the following configuration in your TOML configs: 
`[apim.event_hub]
service_url="https://<your-domain>:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}services"`
and try restarting the server and share the observations

Comment: Thank you @Athiththan After updating '[apim.event_hub]' config I still see errors. `WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.loader.KeyManagerConfigurationDataRetriever} - Failed retrieving Key Manager Configurations from remote endpoint` then 
`ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.exception.GlobalThrowableMapper} - An unknown exception has been captured by the global exception mapper. feign.RetryableException: Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [my-hostname] executing GET https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Comment: Have you tried updating the `internal_hostname` configuration in the `deployment.toml`?

Comment: @Athiththan I have just tried your suggestion adding `internal_hostname` pointing towards my-hostname under `[server]` (is that correct block to put it? - I've not seen any documentation for this configuration setting. Unfortunately, it did not appear to resolve the error; I get exactly the exception same as before `Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [my-hostname] executing GET https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token/.well-known/openid-configuration`